# symfony "<?php" tag in every rendered page

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I was looking at my symfony code, and in every rendered page I have the "?php" tag before the normal html heading (and I dont know why, of course)

```
<?php<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

My controller is very simple:

```
<?php

namespace PUC\PanolBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
        $session->start();
        $lessons=array('CA01','MA02');
        $session->set('user','Drak');
        $session->set('lessons',$lessons);
        return $this->render('PUCPanolBundle:html:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And my index.html.twig starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Titulo{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/estilos.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.11.1.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-regional-es.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Clearing cache also throws php tag:

```
lamp@ubuntu:/var/www/html/symfony$ php app/console cache:clear
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
<?phplamp@ubuntu:/var/www/html/symfony$
```

And Im having thoughts about re-installing symfony :P

---

**SOLVED**

After re-installing symfony this annoying php tag was still there. Since it was a clear installation, my project files were definitely the problem. At the end, I previously had declare an empty Controller that I haven't used yet, with only a ... (yes, you guessed right) php tag inside of it.

Thanks to all for the help :)

Comment: If you do a `die()` in your app.php, is it still there?

Comment: Sounds like your have in some displayable template a <?php, probably in a yaml that thinks it is a php template. Did you check in /app/Resources/views ?

Comment: @Maerlyn it's only there when I use "app_dev.php". For instance, if I check http://localhost/symfony/web/config.php I dont get the php tag

Comment: @Koalabaerchen I dont have any twig files there. it's an empty folder.